# How to set the pose of a box importing data

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi there! I am using `gazebo-11` to test the **navigation algorithm** based on **visual odometry** implemented on NASA's Curiosity rover.

In particular, I created a stereo camera model and I made it move along a line and take photos at a certain rate. In order to simulate osbtacles I introduced **manually** (it took me a great amount of time!!!) in the `.world` file a number of boxes (about 200) which are different from each other in terms of dimensions, position and orientation.

Is there a way to import from a `.txt` file (or other formats) the information about **pose and size** of each **box** so that a box of such size and pose is actually introduced in the Gazebo world (the GUI)?

Probably I have to write a plugin or something similar. Than you so much in advance!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25787/how-to-set-the-pose-of-a-box-importing-data/) by [Simone](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24349/simone/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 30 on 2020-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yes, you can write a world plugin and spawn the models dynamically at runtime.

You can prepare your input data as a yaml file (probably the easiest) and read it in with yaml-cpp. Then you can construct model messages based on that input and publish them so that gazebo can then spawn the models.

See the [GUIExampleSpawnWidget](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo11/examples/plugins/gui_overlay_plugin_spawn/GUIExampleSpawnWidget.cc#L82) example (ignore the gui part).

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2020-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Simone](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24349/simone/) on 2020-09-10**:
Thank you so much!!